# How do I find any attributes in calling code?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, mstest

I have a test setup where I decorate tests with attributes telling if a test can run under some circumstances. Deep down in my code I want to check if the test method has a certain attribute. Can this be accomplished?

My tests look like this:

```
[TestClass, ParallelSeleniumTest, ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class ExportIncident : ViewTest
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("ExcludeFromBuildServer"), SupportedBrowsers(Browser.FireFox)]
    public void Export()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And deep down where I want to assert the `SupportedBrowserAttribute` value my code looks like this:

```
internal static RemoteWebDriver CreateDriver()
{
    // ReSharper disable HeuristicUnreachableCode
    switch (TestRunSettings.BrowserToUse)
    {
        case Browser.Firefox:
            return CreateFirefoxDriver();
        case Browser.Chrome:
            return CreateChromeDriver();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

`BrowserToUse` is a constant in a file.

`CreateDriver` is called from `ViewTest` constructor:

```
public abstract class ViewTest : WebTest
{
    protected ViewTest()
    {
        Driver = SeleniumManager.CreateDriver();
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post the code in question

Comment: Can you show some code examples? And do you really want your _production_ code to check if it was called by a _test_ method or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @RenéVogt it is all test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crawl up the stack frames like this:

```
MethodBase testMethod = null;
int framesSkipped = 0;

do 
{
    testMethod = (new StackFrame(framesSkipped++)).GetMethod();
} while (!testMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false).Any());

SupportBrowserAttribute sba = testMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SupportBrowserAttribute)).
    FirstOrDefault() as SupportBrowserAttribute;
```

So I go up the stack until I find a method that has the `TestMethod` attribute. And then I try to get the `SupportBrowser` attribute.

If the test method does not have such an attribute, `sba` will be `null`. Otherwise you can read it's properties and use them in your `switch`.

Comment: It looked very promising but once I tried it I realized that the stack frame does not contain the method since `CreateDriver` is called from base class constructor. Updated my question with this code.

Comment: @Drutten Strange, I think as long as there is no multi-threading or something like this, your test method _has_ to be on the call stack. I can only imagine that there has happened some compiler optimization like inlining your test method.

Comment: My guess is that the class is initialized by the test framework before any method is invoked.

Comment: yes that may happen with static classes, but your code didn't look like that. Well, that was my best shot, sorry I can't help you better.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using a class attribute instead (not perfect):

```
[TestClass, ParallelSeleniumTest, ExcludeFromCodeCoverage, SupportedBrowsers(Browser.FireFox)]
public class ExportIncident : ViewTest
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("ExcludeFromBuildServer")]
    public void Export()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in `ViewTest` I do:

```
public abstract class ViewTest : WebTest
{
    private RemoteWebDriver _driver;

    protected ViewTest()
    {
        Driver = SeleniumManager.CreateDriver();
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver Driver
    {
        get { return _driver; }
        set
        {
            var attribute = GetType().GetCustomAttribute<OnlySupportsBrowsersAttribute>();

            if (attribute != null && !attribute.Browsers.Any(x => x == TestRunSettings.BrowserToUse))
            {
                Assert.Inconclusive($"Browser {TestRunSettings.BrowserToUse} is not supported by this test");
            }

            _driver = value;
        }
    }
}
```